# How can the user change his number during a loop in WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a little program that chooses a random number and the user has 5 attempts to guess the right number. I'm doing it with a `for` loop. That's my code:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int nbMagique = r.Next(1, 10);
    int nombreUser=165;
    bool nbJuste=false;
    for (int essais = 5; essais != 0 && nombreUser != nbMagique || nbJuste == true; essais--)
    {
        if (nombreUser == nbMagique)
        {
            lblCond.Text = "WOW INCREDIBLE!";
            nbJuste = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (nombreUser < nbMagique)
            {
                lblCond.Text = "Lower!";
            }
            else
            {
                lblCond.Text = "Higher!";
            }
        }

        lblChance.Text = Convert.ToString(essais);

        //I tried to make the program wait 5 seconds
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        if (essais == 4 || essais == 5)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        }
        else if (essais == 3)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        } 
        else if(essais==2)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
        }
        else if(essais==1)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried waiting 5 seconds but it doesn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you have to use a `Timer` or something similar instead of the `for` loop here.

Comment: Why do you think you need to wait? The general flow of this should look like this: 1) user input 2) check input 3) if correct: done 4) else: goto 1)

Comment: Using this System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) you are going to freeze the ui thread for 5 seconds. You could always run this code inside a task or thread or more easily in a winform timer

Comment: I don't think that any timer here could help the OP reach their intents

Comment: You seem to be missing code that reads the user's input. Something like `nombreUser = int.Parse(txtInput.Text);` Also - you should not loop inside the click handler, the click handler should process a single attempt (so the user can enter a number and then click the button).

Comment: You're treating an event driven interface as it was a console application. Let users click a Button to submit the number they guessed. Use a `int` field to keep track of the number of guesses. `int nombreUser=165;` is quite outside the `int nbMagique = r.Next(1, 10);` range. Use a TextBox to let the users insert a number and `int.TryParse()` it to validate the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting your main thread to sleep. This makes that your main thread can't listen to user input.

> In a UI driven application, Never, ever, let your UI thread do anything that takes a time longer than users are willing to wait.

Usually people want a response within 100 msec: if you try to type the number 12345, and you have to wait 100 msec after the 1 before you see the 2, you'll be annoyed.

We're not afraid of classes, so let's create a class that plays the game for you. Apparently you want to inform the user by sending messages to a text box, and you want to change the background color of some control. When the game object is created a magic number is created. Method guess(int) will perform a guess

```
class MyGame
{
    private readonly static random = new Random();

    public MyGame()
    {
        this.MagicNumber = this.random.Next(1, 10);
        this.GuessCount = 0
    } 

    public TextBox Messagebox {get; set;}     // shows higher / lower / ok
    public Control ColorControl {get; set;}   // Change the color when almost out of guesses
    public int MagicNumber {get; private set;}
    public int GuessCount {get; private set;}

    public void Guess(int guess)
    {
        // update the MessageBox:
        if (guess > this.MagicNumber)
            this.MessageBox.Text = ...
        else if (guess < this.MagicNumber)
            this.MessageBox.Text = ...
        else
            this.MessageBox.Text = ...

        // update the backgound color:
        ++this.GuessCount;
        if (this.GuessCount < ...)
           this.ColorControl.BackColor = ...
        else if (this.GuessCount < ...)
           this.ColorControl.BackColor = ...
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Now in your form:

```
private MyGame game = null;

void StartNewGame()
{
    this.game = new MyGame();
    this.game.MessageBox = this.lblCond;  // the text box for messages.
    this.game.ColorControl = this; // the complete form changes color after a few guesses
}
```

When do you want to start a game? When the form loads? or when the user presses the button new Game?

```
void OnButtonNewGameClicked(Button sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, this.ButtonNewGame)
     {
          // start a new Game
          this.StartNewGame();
     }
}
```

How should the user do a new guess: just type a number in a text box, or type a number plus press button guess?

```
void OnButtonGuessClicked(Button sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, this.ButtonGuess)
     {    // User pressed guess button
          string input = this.ButtonGuess.Text;
          int guess = Int32.Parse(input);
          // TODO: catch exception and proper error if not a proper number

          this.Game.Guess(guess);
          // this will display the result and color the form
      }
 }
```

The nice thing about this separate class is that you can easily change your game without changing your form: you can decide to color the textbox instead of the complete form. You can decide to make your input a NumericUpDown instead of a TextBox, so people can't by accident type anything that is not a number.

> In a windows forms application try to separate the user input/output from the data handling.

This way, it will be easier to change your forms without changing the data handling. It will also be easier to unit test your data handling (because it has no forms in it)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that you are running your logic loop within your button click handler.

You should be using the button click to obtain your user entered number (I assume that is your intent) and use this in your logic loop elsewhere.

Ideally you want to run your logic within a Task. That way you can have it sit stop processing whilst it waits for new user data and it wont freeze the user interface.